# Facebook Graph API - not returning all comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I use Facebook Graph API to fetch comments on pages

`https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=`

but the API is not returning all the comments (only the first level).

In example:

http://www.imedical.cz/aktualni-clanky/aktualni-clanek

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.imedical.cz/aktualni-clanky/aktualni-clanek

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/object/comments) you would set `filter=stream` to get replies to comments.